# Touch event of a bigger subview than it's parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a subview which is bigger than it's parent view. Now I need to get the touch event of entire subview. But I am getting the touch event for the area of the size of it's parent. Is there any way to achieve the above. Any idea will be appreciable.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940825/uiview-let-subviews-receive-touches-but-not-main-view

Comment: Could you add the code you use to show the views? Is the `parentView.clipsToBounds` set to `true` or `false`?

Comment: parentView.clipsToBounds = false

Comment: @NitinGohel I had already implemented hitTest but it's never called